# Generating a random dictionary and coloring associated graph

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, random, graph

I would like to generate a random dictionary starting from an array with 5 elements. That dictionary would represent a planar graph.
How can i generate a random dictionary that is a planar graph whose values and keys are the 5 elements of the array?
This is what I tried:

```
q = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
d = {i: sample([j for j in q if i != j], randrange(1, len(q) - 1))
     for i in q}
```

Here is an example of the graph it generates:

```
{0: [1], 1: [4, 3], 2: [4], 3: [4], 4: [0, 2]}
```

As you can see, the problem is that *it is not creating a proper adjacency matrix* (3 is connected with 1 but 1 is not in its adjancey matrix)
Some of you suggested me an already asked question, but the answer to that question is pretty complex as it generates a very big planar graph, the thing I’m trying to do here is a simple code that generate a small planar graph with 5 vertices. Keep in mind that the planarity of the graph can always be checked with `checkplanarity` from `networkx`, more on that [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.planarity.check_planarity.html), the issue I need to solve is the adjacency of the matrix.

the reason I'm doing this is to then color the generated graph with four colors using the following function named `coloring`, and the matrix problem prevents me from coloring it proprely so that same colors never touch. To feed the function `coloring` with the created graph I do the following:

```
def coloring(adj, V):
    result = [-1] * V
    result[0] = 0
    available = [False] * V
    # add values to adj matrices
    for y in range(0, V):
        for x in adj[y]:
            if y not in adj[x]:
                adj[x].append(y)

    for u in range(1, V):
        for i in adj[u]:
            if (result[i] != -1):
                available[result[i]] = True
        cr = 0
        while cr < V:
            if (available[cr] == False):
                break

            cr += 1

        result[u] = cr

        for i in adj[u]:
            if (result[i] != -1):
                available[result[i]] = False

    for u in range(V):
        print("Vertex", u, " --->  Color", result[u])
```

To feed the function `coloring` with the created graph `d` I do the following:

```
coloring([node for node in d.values()], 5)
```

Comment: `and that has as values the elements of the array?` ... what does that mean?

Comment: Might help if you explain at a high level what a planar graph is (as represented by a list of values)

Comment: @chitown88 a planar graph is a graph that can be drawn in to the 2 plane with out any lines crossing each other. For example of you draw a rectangle an the corner points are the knots in the graph that would be a planar graph

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate a large random planar graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232048/generate-a-large-random-planar-graph)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58050200/how-to-draw-a-planar-graph-with-networkx

Comment: @TomAarsen Unfortunately it doesn’t answer my question. I have edited the question explaining why

Comment: How can you ensure that it is a planar graph? Generating some random graph in your structure seems to be the easier part. Do you need to solve only the adjacency of the matrix?

Comment: @DanielTuzes it can be done with the `checkplanarity` function provided by `networkx`I added it to the question. And yes, what I want to fix is the adjacency of the matrix. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do this with numpy.

1. Let's create a random matrix with random number between 0 to 9 of size `nxn` = `5x5`
2. Next, let's sum the matrix with its transpose to ensure that it is symmetrix
3. Fix the diagonal `with np.fill_diagonal` to remove self loops
4. Define a condition `connectivity`, the larger it is, lower the number of connections in your random graph.
5. Finally convert the matrix into a dictionary
6. Plot.

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

def random_graph(vertices, connectivity):
    #Creates random symmetric graph
    arr = np.random.randint(0,10,(vertices,vertices))
    sym = (arr+arr.T)
    
    #removing self loops with fixing diagonal
    np.fill_diagonal(sym,0)
    
    #connectivity of graph -> 0 for highest connections, 9 for least connections
    mat = (sym>connectivity).astype(int)
    
    #convert to dictionary
    G = {k:[i for i,j in enumerate(v) if j==1] for k,v in enumerate(mat)}
    return G
```

Generating graph with high connections (connectivity = 0) -

```
G = random_graph(5, 0)
g = nx.Graph(G)
print(G)
nx.draw(g)
```

```
{0: [1, 2, 3, 4],
 1: [0, 2, 3, 4],
 2: [0, 1, 3, 4],
 3: [0, 1, 2, 4],
 4: [0, 1, 2, 3]}
```

[image]

Generating graph with lower connections (connectivity = 8) -

```
G = random_graph(5, 8)
g = nx.Graph(G)
print(G)
nx.draw(g)
```

```
{0: [2, 3], 
 1: [2, 3, 4], 
 2: [0, 1, 4], 
 3: [0, 1], 
 4: [1, 2]}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, but I get the following error in the `random_graph` function that you have provided me with: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\besan\OneDrive\Desktop\LAM da correggere\test.py", line 56, in <module>    
    G = random_graph(5, 0)
  File "c:\Users\besan\OneDrive\Desktop\LAM da correggere\test.py", line 46, in random_graph
    arr = np.random.randint(0,10,(n,n))
NameError: name 'n' is not defined`

Comment: furthermore, how can I avoid that nodes are connected to themselfes?

Comment: i have edited the question adding more context, helping you help me

Comment: Updated my answer, the `n` was a bug on my part, fixed it! Also, added an additional part to remove self-loops. Do check the answer and if it worked for you then do mark & vote the answer. let me know if you need any specific clarifications on the solution above.

Comment: thank you, it works perfectly now, I was going crazy on this script. One more thing, I was thinking of randomizing the connectivity by generating a random number between 0 and 10. Do you have a better idea on how to add a simple element of randomness to the graph?

Comment: `One more thing, I was thinking of randomizing the connectivity by generating a random number between 0 and 10` could you elaborate on this with an example? maybe i could spend some time as adding that as an additional part to the above solution :)

Comment: Do make sure to mark and vote the above answer if it solved your current problem though, motivates me to solve any future problems that you post! thanks!

Comment: marked and also upvoted, if yo have any ideas on some randomization for the graph let me know :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241457/discussion-between-akshay-sehgal-and-emilio).

Comment: if I try to do create a graph with more than 5 vertices, I get the following error when coloring it with the `coloring` function: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\besan\OneDrive\Desktop\LAM da stampare\stacktest.py", line 79, in <module>
    coloring([node for node in G.values()], 5)
  File "c:\Users\besan\OneDrive\Desktop\LAM da stampare\stacktest.py", line 22, in coloring
    if (result[i] != -1): IndexError: list index out of range`

Answer (score 1):

With a slight modification to your code, you can symmetrize your graph:

```py
import random
random.seed(0)

q = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
d = {i: set(random.sample([j for j in q if i != j], random.randrange(1, len(q) - 1)))
     for i in q}
```

Now symmetrize:

```py
for node in d:
    for link_target in d[node]:
        d[link_target].add(node)
```

This way nodes are not connected to themselves, just as in your code. You still have to verify whether the graph is planar.

### Set the number of edges

If you wish to fix the number of edges to `k`, here's what you can do:

1. generate a triangular matrix with zeros in the diagonal, using zeros (false) and ones (true) to represent connectivity between edges. You can do it by random shuffling `k` ones and N*(N-1)/2 zeros and distributing them onto non-diagonal places of the triangular matrix.
2. add the transpose of the matrix to itself
3. convert the matrix to the dictionary format you prefer.

Note: you still have to confirm whether the graph is planar.

Comment: i have edited the question adding more context, helping you help me

Comment: Without ensuring the symmetry, by omitting the for loop, the code above produces `{0: {1, 4}, 1: {2, 4}, 2: {1, 4}, 3: {0, 1, 2}, 4: {0, 1}}`. Using the for loop to ensure symmetry, the result is `{0: {1, 3, 4}, 1: {0, 2, 3, 4}, 2: {1, 3, 4}, 3: {0, 1, 2}, 4: {0, 1, 2}}` Does it solve your problem?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't. In the question I published my entire coloring program so that maybe you can understand what's wrong. Again, my final goal is to color the graph with four colors without having same colors adjacent to oneanother

Comment: How do you feed `coloring` with `u` and `d`?

Comment: I have just updated the question explaining more on that